# What does it even mean?: "Perturbation theory developed around minima of potential (vacuum) is stable."

Tags: path-integral, vacuum, perturbation-theory, symmetry-breaking

(Context: QFT, spontaneous symmetry breaking):

What I have understood from reading the path integral version of the story is that this "vacuum" is actually the classical solution [i.e. which satisfies the exact, interacting, equations of motion ("on-shell") of the theory] and the perturbations are the "quantum fluctuations" to this trajectory. [Quantum in the sense that these paths are not classical solutions but there is non-zero quantum amplitude for these trajectories which thus contribute in the path integral.]

This story makes sense to me but I don't quite understand where the word "vacuum" is coming from. Is it just semantics or is really somehow related to the actual interacting vacuum in the hilbert space of the theory (eigenstate of hamiltonian with minimum energy eigenvalue)? If there is a connection at all, I wish to understand its mathematical origin.